# How to do a complex lookup like this?

Tags: python, django, lookup, django-queryset

OK, maybe it isn't complex, but i am stuck at this. I have this models schema:

```
Evento(models.Model):
    aprobado = models.BooleanField()
    mod = models.ForeignKey(model=Mod, null=True)
    [...]

Mod(models.Model):
    activo = models.BooleanField()
    [...]
```

I want to retrieve *objects with `aprobado == True` and `mod == None` or (if mod != None) `mod.activo == False`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ["Q" object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and a bitwise OR operator (which is overloaded for Q objects to represent SQL OR).

```
from django.db.models import Q

queryset = Evento.objects.filter(Q(mod__isnull=True, aprobado=True) | Q(mod__isnull=False, mod__activo=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be verbose and use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
Evento \
    .objects \
    .filter(
        Q(aprobado==True, mod__isnull=True) |
        Q(mod__isnull=False, mod__activo=False)
```